# the IBM Content Navigator Plugin Jar File was not found

Tags: plugins, jar, dojo, websphere, ibm-content-navigator

I am working on an **IBM Content Navigator Plugin**.
I want to add a new plugin to **IBM Content Navigator**. 
I have the jar file of the plugin uploaded to a **WebSphere** server, and I can reach that jar file by using the browser,

---

however I get an error when I do the same using the **IBM Content Navigator Plugin** screen. 
I am unable to load the plugin jar file to **IBM Content Navigator**.

---

I have tried both URL Path and File Path; I keep getting this error:
"*The plug-in JAR file was not found at the specified URL. Ensure that the JAR file is on the web application server and that the URL and file name are correct*."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer comes too late, but this can occurr when the Plugin-Class reference in the plugin's jar manifest is wrong or missing. In our manifest it was missing.

See also:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014913620#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014913713

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer would not be useful for the person who posted this question 6 years ago, but can help fellow ICN developers to troubleshoot if they face this problem.

There could be couple of more possible scenarios other than mentioned by others ::
1) you dont have correct permissions on the JAR file. Normally whenever I transfer the file on ICN server, I update the permissions on the JAR file to 777.
2) Sometimes if you have deployed a plugin JAR file with name "ABC.jar" and you want to update the plugin, avoid using same name as the old JAR file name. ICN sometimes act weird to not recognize the JAR file with the old name. Rename your new JAR file, say "ABC1.jar" and use it while configuring.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, my solution was restart the websphere server.